# How to post (mutate) data using it inside loop?

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I have endpoints' values. For example:

```
const endpoints = ["group1", "group2", "group3"]
```

I want to post using mutate (**react query**) by clicking the single button.
Every post request returns to me an object with info. I want to load useState by receiving values from each url.

Something like this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < endpoints.length; i++){
    const res = await axios.post("some_link/{endpoints[i]}")
    setValues(curr => [..curr, res])
}
```

I tried to make it using Promise.all as adviced chat gpt. However it didn't work.

Comment: Promise.all looks like the way to go here. Please provide your solution and the error thrown.

Comment: Promise.all will throw error if some input return error. I don't need this. Multiple requests shouldn't be stopped if one of them throws an error.

Comment: In that case, use `Promise.allSettled` - that won't stop execution when any of the promises rejects.